# C++ DLL Interop with C#: Exposing multidimensional arrays of unknown size, and memory-management

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, multidimensional-array

I have a C++ library that does some hardcore financial mathematics (Quantlib).  I have a normal C++ dll built against it, which exposes a lightweight interface to a C# front-end app to allow users to pass in various parameters, run scenarios etc.  The dll then returns the data for display.

I'm really unclear on how to handle the interface between the dll and the C# layer however, and in particular I have no idea where the memory allocation/deallocation is handled, i.e. in C# or the dll

In essence, I'd like my dll to return a class or struct that holds a 2-dimensional array of values (double, char* etc).  I won't know the **size** of this array at the time I call the dll, so it'll have to be allocated by the dll itself I guess.

At the moment, I have the dll returning a looooooooong char* with a pipe-delimited list of values.  This seems to work, but it doesn't strike me as a particularly elegant solution.

Any help, guys?

**EDIT**

thanks a lot for all your feedback.  Sorry, I haven't done any DLL programming in years, hence the slightly stupid question.

I decided to simply treat the 2d array as a 1d array with a height/width offset on the C++ side, and to just live with guessing the size of the array up-front.  Creating a 2d array on the C# side, and marshalling it to C++ in this way seems to work fine.

Here's what I have.  Thoughts, anyone?

C#:

```
    [DllImport(<dllPath>, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void ChangeArray2d(double[,] arr, int l1, int l2);

    //populated with some sample values
    double[,] arr = new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
    ChangeArray2d(arr, arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1));
```

C++:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) void ChangeArray2d( double* arrayin, int height, int width)
{
    for (int n = 0; n<height; n++){
        for (int m = 0; m<width; m++){
            arrayin[n*width+m]  = arrayin[n*width+m] + 100;
        }
    };
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Post some code to talk about - for example, desired unmanaged function prototype. If you want to learn about managed-unmanaged interoperability, take a look at Marshal class, specifically, AllocHGlobal and different Copy overloads.

Comment: The rule is: "he who allocates, also deallocates". If you allocate in your C++ code you'll also need to export a deallocator.

Comment: @David: yep. But returning a deallocator is very complex thing. It's much easier and flexible to adapt "calling side manages memory" rule if it is possible at all.

Comment: @Ivan Exporting a deallocator is trivial. You just export a function called `free` which receives a pointer. The C# code just calls `free` when its done with the `IntPtr` that it received earlier.

Comment: @David: Yeah. And then you have to call it (native call) and handle exceptions correctly and the like. Why to bother here? If you can't know data size (for example data size is changing from the outside so you can't request size and then get data as a second call because it could be another size already) this approach can be useful. But it is more complex to write reliably not mention to debug if something went wrong.

Comment: @Ivan You're already P/Invoking so what's the problem with another one. You have to handle all those issues for the call that fills out the memory. Allocating memory at the caller is better if it can be done. However, sometimes that's inconvenient if the generation of the array is expensive you don't want to do it twice, once to work out the size, and then once again to fill out the callers memory.

Comment: The question has little to do with C#, the exact same considerations are necessary when your code is called from C or C++ client code.  Solve that first, the C# case becomes easy.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is common pattern to allocate buffer, pass it (with buffer size as maximum amount of data you can handle at once) to C++ native function that will fill it and then to handle data/free buffer. Or reuse buffer.

If your native function allocates buffer for you and you should free it afterwards - it is vary fragile contract and also prohibits memory reuse. E.g. if you need to call this function 20 times - you'll have 20 unnecessary allocations.

Something like that:

```
private int YourNativeFunctionStub(IntPtr buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    int writtenToBufferBytes = bufferSize; // if it wrote less to buffer - it should return correct count of bytes
    // here your library fills the buffer with data
    return writtenToBufferBytes;
}

private double[] GetArrayFromNative()
{
    int bufsize = 1024; // probably you should find it by calling another func from your library?

    IntPtr nativeBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufsize);
    try
    {
        int bytesReceivedInBuffer = YourNativeFunctionStub(nativeBuffer, bufsize);

        int receivedArrayLength = bytesReceivedInBuffer / sizeof(double);
        var managedArray = new double[receivedArrayLength];
        Marshal.Copy(nativeBuffer, managedArray, 0, receivedArrayLength);
        return managedArray;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeBuffer);
    }
}
```

**UPD**: see the Hans' comment.

Comment: Explicit manual marshaling like this is a bad idea.  The pinvoke marshaller has no trouble with it and knows how to avoid the extra copy when it can.  Just declare the function with an array[] argument.

Comment: @Hans OP's actually asking about 2D arrays. Are they easy with the default marshaller?

Comment: @David: AFAIK 2D arrays is just a wrapper with tricky indexer property and support of getting length by each dimension. So yes, marshaller is able to work with them (and can't work with jagged arrays): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21.aspx

Comment: Just checked SSCLI sources. Multidimensional arrays internally are just plain arrays with length equal to product of lengths of each dimension.